# Composer and migration issue, need guide to fix it

Tags: php, laravel

So sorry for the question title, not sure what to mention.

I have a situation, I had a `translations` table but some how I had to install a package `voyager`. In this package there is also migration for `translations` table. I tried to find a way to change table name, but I failed and then I decided to rename my own `translations` table. So I did it by creating a migration as you can see following

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::rename("translations", "new_translations");
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::rename("new_translations", "translations");
}
```

Now whenever I try to execute `php artisan migrate:rollback` it returns an error

```
Cannot declare class
 CreateTranslationsTable, because the name is already in use

  at F:\xampp\htdocs\project-name\database\migrations\2019_09_19_094436_create_tran
slations_table.php:40
    36|
    37|              Schema::dropIfExists('translations');
    39|     }
  > 40| }
```

Can someone kindly guide me how can I fix the issue, I would really appreciate.

Comment: In your `database/migrations` folder, find the migration that creates the translations table, and rename the file and the class name as well.

Comment: @nakov what should be the name

Comment: `CreateNewTranslations` for example. It has to be different then the error

Comment: You can not have two classes with the same name within the same namespace. So either change the class name as @nakov suggests, or put your class in its own namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue isn't with the actual migration (although you do need to change the table name) but it's rather to do with the file name and the class name, as stated by navok in the comments.

If you find your own migration inside of the `database/migrations` folder and rename it from `xxxxxx_xxxxxx_create_translations_table.php` to something like `xxxxx_xxxxxx_create_new_translations_table.php` and then inside of that file change the class name from `CreateTranslationsTable` to `CreateNewTranslationsTable` and re-run the migration.

It appears that the migration inside of the package that you installed also has a class name of `CreateTranslationsTable` so the easiest option is to change the name of your own.

The only issue with this is, you will have to run a fresh migration.

`php artian migrate:fresh`.